# How to add class to table in froala editor?

Tags: editor, froala

How can I add some css classes to tables made in froala editor? I need it because I use some bootstrap classes on tables and I want to add them to tables from the editor.

I need to add this: `class="table table-striped table-hover responsive"`

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCZXo.png

You'll see the difference in the code:

1) This is what I get now:  `<table>`

2) And this is what I need:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover responsive">
```

Comment: please explain clearly

Comment: edited; I hope that it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I can use function str_replace before saving to the database. I'll use this solution:

```
function repairTables($text){
    return str_replace('<table width="100%">', '<table class="table table-striped table-hover responsive">', $text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can also add the classes like this:

```
$('div#froala-editor table').addClass('table table-bordered');
```

If you want to add it on insertion of the table, it's possible to override the default Froala behaviour:

```
$.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('tableInsert', {
callback: function (cmd, rows, cols) {
  this.table.insert(rows, cols);
  this.popups.hide('table.insert');
  $('div#froala-editor table').addClass('table table-bordered');
}
```

});